# Best way to search multiple fields laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I try to create a function for search using 8 fields. I use this way in the bottom 
but it's return any offer has one of this given values .
what I want is the offer he has all values searching .
The user can searching with any field he want 
what is the best way to do that whithout a lot of condition if

```
 public function search(Request $request)
        {
            $hashids = new Hashids();
            $city = $request->city;
            $category = $request->category;
            $type = $request->type;
            $rooms = $request->rooms;
            $minPrice = $request->minPrice;
            $maxPrice = $request->maxPrice;
            $minSpace = $request->minSpace;
            $maxSpace = $request->maxSpace;
            $citySearch = DB::table('offers')->where('city',$city);
            $categorySearch = DB::table('offers')->where('category_id',$category);
            $typeSearch = DB::table('offers')->where('type',$type);
            $roomsSearch = DB::table('offers')->where('rooms',$rooms);
            $priceSearch = DB::table('offers')
                ->whereBetween('price', [$minPrice, $maxPrice]);
            $spaceSearch = DB::table('offers')
                ->whereBetween('space', [$minSpace, $maxSpace]);
            $result_search = $citySearch->union($categorySearch)->union($typeSearch)->union($roomsSearch)->union($priceSearch)->union($spaceSearch)->get();
            $view = View::make('ajax.search',compact('result_search','hashids'))->render();
            return response()->json(['html'=>$view]);
        }
```

Comment: so like "WHERE field = value AND otherfield = value AND ..."?

Comment: what if the field is empty !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using this search as a way to filter down the possibilities you can take this approach, which only applies a condition to the query as long as the input is set.

This also takes it down to one query for you, instead of having to union a lot of queries:

```
$projects = Project::

when($request->year_from, function($query) use ($request){
    $query->where('delivery_year', '>=', $request->year_from);
})
->when($request->year_to, function($query) use ($request){
    $query->where('delivery_year', '<=', $request->year_to);
})
->when( $request->delivery_month_from, function($query) use ($request){
    $query->where('delivery_month', '>=', $request->delivery_month_from);
})
->when( $request->delivery_month_to, function($query) use ($request){
    $query->where('delivery_month', '<=', $request->delivery_month_to);
})
->when( $request->product_group, function($query) use ($request){
    $query->whereHas('products', function($q) use ($request) {
        $q->whereHas('group', function($qi) use ($request){
            $qi->whereIn('id', $request->product_group);
        });
    });
})
->get();
```

**Edit for whereBetween:**

```
$projects = Project::

when(($minSpace && $maxSpace), function($query) {
    $query->whereBetween('space', [$minSpace, $maxSpace]);
})->get()
```

This checks if both $minSpace and $maxSpace are set and bigger than zero (equals to true)

Comment: i'ts working tk yu but i have question how to use this way with whereBetween() function